# rest service throw exception on null field

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

i have the following jpa class served by a Spring @RestController:

```
@Entity
public class LocationContract
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Date startDate;
    private Integer duration;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    private House house;
    private Long registrationNumber;
    private Double annualFee;
    private Boolean flatTax;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
              name = "contracts_tenants", 
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id"), 
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id"))
    private List<Tenant> tenants = new ArrayList<Tenant>();
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "locationContract",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();

    //normal getters and setters
```

When i try to access a field with some null I get

```
Could not write JSON: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "com.steeve.housekeeper.domain.LocationContract.getDuration()" is null]
```

It makes no sense, i would expect something like {"property": null} not an exception. This behivour is present only in this class, all other classes works as expected...
Any ideas?

Comment: i have restricted the problem to 2 fields: startDate and duration. All other fields can be null... it makes less sense than before.